# Program not polygons

Tags: java, swing, graphics, polygon, mouselistener

I got a program running and I call this class and well, after coding it it should do stuff when the mouse drags, but it just does nothing, where is the error? I mean it should work based on the code, but it just stares at me with apparent ambivalent contempt, mocking me.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class simpleWhiteBoard extends JFrame
{

    protected int lastX, lastY;

    public  simpleWhiteBoard()
    {

        super("Smile white board");

        lastX = 0;
        lastY = 0;

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.white);

        addMouseListener(new positionRecorder());
        addMouseMotionListener(new LineDrawer());

        setBounds(10, 20, 450, 400);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    protected void record(int x, int y)
    {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;

    }

    private class positionRecorder extends MouseAdapter
    {

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
            record(e.getX(), e.getY());

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            record(e.getX(), e.getY());

        }

    }


    private class LineDrawer extends MouseMotionAdapter
    {

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {

            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            Polygon p = new Polygon(Constants.X, Constants.Y, Constants.X.length);
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillPolygon(p);

            g.setColor(Color.red);

            p = new Polygon(Constants.X, Constants.Y, Constants.X.length);

        }

    }

}//finale
```

Comment: It's got many mistakes, too many to enumerate, and does not use Java graphics correctly at all, including and especially calling `getGraphics()`, not drawing in a JComponent or JPanel, not overrideing a `paintComponent` method -- as if you're just guessing. If this were my project, I wouldn't make assumptions that it should work. Instead I'd check out the Java graphics tutorial to see how to do drawing correctly. You can search the site for many examples of just this sort of thing as well.

Comment: Please start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the tutorial!